# Custom MarkupExtension in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, markup-extensions

I would like to create my own `MarkupExtension` (like `Binding`, `TemplateBinding`...)

How can I do it for Universal Apps like I did in WPF?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/7232264-add-markup-extensions-to-and-improve-winrt-xaml)?

Comment: No, I didn't. Already voted. Thank you!

Comment: Congratulations, you got it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.markupextension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I has a sad, but no. UWP doesn't *currently* support custom markup extensions.

In some cases you can work around this by using bindings and converters. For example, to use a resource string (not using `x:Uid`), I have a converter that doesn't actually need a value, only a parameter (the resource id).

For example, I might bind as follows:

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{x:Bind Language, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource Localize}, ConverterParameter=MyResourceId}"
/>
```

(This binding doesn't need a path, but I bind to `Language` anyway, which allows switching languages on the fly.)

[More about the `LocalizeConverter` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40789743/3968276).

But anyway. If I'd been doing WPF, this would have been a markup extension. `Binding` itself is, of course, a markup extension, so as long as you can work within its constraints, it is a possible workaround.

**EDIT**

I just want to highlight the link Clemens gave in his comment to the OP:

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/7232264-add-markup-extensions-to-and-improve-winrt-xaml

**UPDATE**

[There is now limited support for custom markup extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.markupextension)! (Hat tip to Michael Hawker's comment.)

Comment: There's some supported subset of them now, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156782/how-does-one-use-the-uwp-markupextension-class.